# Seeking portable version of QGIS running on MacOS or Windows

Tags: qgis

I have to remotely help dozens of users install QGIS 3.10. on their computers. Their computers are heterogeneous. In 90 % of the cases the installation works well but for some users it does not work.

Are there portable versions of QGIS 3.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the 3.22 version available in this github repository and it got a lot.

link https://github.com/pigreco/QGIS_portable_3x

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-g_GH-JqsPqPRd-7mpn0NxmbF_nSy5z5/view?usp=sharing) this is the version I used it has GRASS and SAGA GIS included. I was able to install the plugins without any problems

Answer (score 2):

Would the [Portable GIS usb](https://portablegis.xyz/post/get/) be a solution for your problem, at least on Windows?

> ### What is it?
>
> Portable GIS is a windows-only set of open source GIS packages ready to install or copy onto a USB stick, and run with no additional configuration.
>
> ### What is it not?
>
> It’s not OSGeo-Live or OSGeo4W
>
> OSGeo-Live provides you with an entire open source GIS operating system, but one that you have to boot into, so it’s separate from your day to day environment. Portable GIS provides a limited subset of the same tools, but accessible in your own environment.
>
> OSGeo4W provides a really easy way of installing all the open source GIS tools on windows, without configuration headaches. Portable GIS provides a subset of those tools, but without the need for installation.
>
> ### What does it contain?
>
> #### Current Version 5.8.1
>
> - Desktop GIS packages QGIS version 2.18.11 LTR
> - FWTools (GDAL and OGR toolkit)
> - Apache2 and Php5
> - PostgreSQL (version 9.1)/Postgis (version 2.1)
> - Mapserver 5.6 and 6, OpenLayers.
> - Python 2.7 with GDAL 1.9 libraries and Psycopg2
> - Loader- for loading gml such as Ordnance Survey Mastermap into a PostgreSQL Database
> - Mapnik
> - Geoserver 2.8
> - Utilities- portable firefox, pdf reader and text editor